# adding views to a subclassed AdminSite using get_urls

Tags: django, view, admin

I've subclassed AdminSite, and I'm trying to add a couple of custom views.

My views work fine when I add them into the urls on one of my apps, but I can't get them working with admin (all the models registered with my new admin site work fine).

```
class HqAdmin(AdminSite):
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(HqAdmin, self).get_urls()
        urls += patterns('',
            url(r'^orders/$',
                self.admin_view(OrderListView.as_view()),
                kwargs={'current_app': self.name},
                name="order-list-page"),
            url(r'^orders/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
                self.admin_view(OrderView.as_view()),
                kwargs={'current_app': self.name},
                name='order-page'),
        )
        return urls

hq_admin = HqAdmin(name='Custom Admin')
```

I'm getting a 404 at /admin/orders/

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the `hq_admin` urls in your url conf?

```
# urls.py
from myproject.admin import hq_admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
   (r'^admin/', include(hq_admin.urls)),
```

Comment: yup, I've got that in there. Thanks Alasdair.